What scripts or plugins would you like to see for Ghidra?
For those of you using Ghidra, are there any scripts or plugins you wish existed to make certain tasks easier or fill a specific gap? Whether it’s a small utility or a more advanced feature, I’d love to hear your ideas!
Looking forward to seeing what you think would be useful !

I'm afraid that your question is subject to closure because being subjective. Please read https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.
